# Accessing method from another class, NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist

so I've been wracking my brains over why this isn't working for an hour now. I have two classes, class One containing an ArrayList of ArrayLists and a method to add another element to that list, and class Two, from which I'm trying to access that method.

```
 public class One
{
    private ArrayList<Element> myarraylist;

    public One()
    {
        myarraylist = new ArrayList<Element>();
    }

    public void addElement(String name)
    {
        myarraylist.add(new Element(name));
    }
}

//Element being another class





public class Two
{
    One database;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Two two = new Two();
        two.startMenu();
    }

    public Two()
    {
        One database = new One();
    }

    public void addElem()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = keyboard.next();
        database.addElement(name);
    }
}

//where startMenu is just a small multiple choice menu thingy
```

Problem is, when I try to run through it and I get to the last line, I get the message: java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried inspecting the objects (I use BlueJ), and the ArrayList is initialized when I just make an instance of class One, but when I make an instance of class Two, the database instance is null.

Thanks in advance for your answers :D

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Your complaining on exception (which you didn't provide), and the parts of code to which exception supposedly related is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the following lines

```
public class Two
{
     One database;

     public Two()
     {
        One database = new One(); 
        //this variable is not the same as the one declared outside the constructor
     }
```

When declaring a variable in a method which has the same name as the variable declared in the class, the modifications which happen on the variable declared inside the method will not be seen in the variable outside the method(because the 2 variables are different). The variable in the method is shadowing the variable from the class.
To differentiate between the two variables you must use the **this** keyword

```
this.database = new One();
```

The final solution should be

```
public class Two
{
     One database;

     public Two()
     {
        this.database = new One(); 
     }
```

The reason you get the **NullPointerException** when doing **database.addElement(name);** is because in your example the **database** is not instatiated beacause the object created is stored in a different variable named **database** and not the one declared as a class attribute.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! I'm literally a baby at this, you just saved my life!